# CentOS and Broadcom Wireless Drivers

Tags: centos, wifi

I'm tired of reading, tired of trying to find a solution myself, that's why I decided to post my question.

I'm following tutorial located at [CentOS Wiki](http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/Laptops/Wireless/Broadcom?action=show#head-a174636ca2f4ad3c5610d78bf2086f51cfd1ea23) to install driver for my wifi device.

However, I'm facing strange error at the begining of the process.

```
make -C /lib/modules/`uname -r`/build/ M=`pwd`
make: *** /lib/modules/2.6.18-194.11.3.el5PAE/build/: File not found
```

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong? This is first time when I try to install Linux on my laptop.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.broadcom.com/docs/linux_sta/README.txt did you try above site for install the driver.

Answer (score 0):

did you install these packages using follwoing command?

yum install kernel-headers kernel-devel gcc

i have tried it is working fine with this command